# Access Angular 2 Inputs (properties) inside constructor

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating some components in order to learn Angular2.

I have this basic html:

```
<h1>test</h1>
<btn [order]="0"></btn>
<btn [order]="1"></btn>
<btn [order]="2"></btn>
```

And in the `ts` I have this:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {DataService} from '../services/DataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'btn',
    template: '<button>test{{ item }}</button>',
    inputs: ['order']
})

export class ButtonComponent {
    items: Array<number>;
    item: number;
    @Input() order;

    constructor(dataService: DataService) {
        console.log(this.order)
    }
}
```

Doing that I get undefined, what am I doing wrong? how can I read the inputs (or an attribute) in order to send data to the class?

**EDIT**

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {DataService} from '../services/DataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'btn',
    template: '<button>test{{ item }}</button>',
    inputs: ['order']
})

export class ButtonComponent {
    items: Array<number>;
    item: number;
    @Input() order;

    ngOnInit(dataService: DataService) {
        this.items = dataService.getItems();
        console.log(this.order)
    }

    constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: You still need to inject `DataService` using the `constructor(dataService: DataService);` but you can't access the `@Input() order;` there yet. You can still access `dataService` from `ngOnInit()` using `this.dataService`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't access them in the constructor, they are not yet initialized. Use `ngOnInit()` instead. For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

```
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
    items: Array<number>;
    item: number;
    @Input() order;

    constructor(dataService: DataService) {  }

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.order);
    }
}
```